# Inserting Data on mysql and vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've got  a table name *stocks* with following Columns :

> ItemID, Item, Serial, Quantity, Category, Class, Unit, Beg_Date

and this is what I coded on vb.net:

```
Private Sub Savebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Savebtn.Click

      Try

         If txtItemID.Text = "" Or txtItemName.Text = "" Or txtQuantity.Text = "" Or cBoxCategory.Text = "" Or cBoxClass.Text = "" Or cBoxUnit.Text = "" Or dtpAdd.Value =""Then

          MsgBox("All fields required!")

        Else            

            ConStr.Open()

            Dim Add_Query As String

            Add_Query = "INSERT INTO Stocks (ItemID,Item,Serial,Quantity,Category,Class,Unit,Beg_Date) VALUES ('" & txtItemID.Text & "','" & txtItemName.Text & "','" & txtSerial.Text & "','" & txtQuantity.Text & "','" & cBoxCategory.Text & "','" & cBoxClass.Text & "','" & cBoxUnit.Text & "','" & dtpAdd.Value & "')"

            Cmd = New MySqlCommand(Add_Query, ConStr)
            Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader
            MsgBox("Successfully Added!")
            Me.Hide()
            ConStr.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Connection Failed!")

    Finally
        ConStr.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Everytime I save the data when user input values it always give me  a

> Mysqlexception error "Connection Failed!"..

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that  my form is already connected to the database.

Comment: I strongly recommend analyzing the exception that is being thrown. Currently you handle all MySql exceptions by simply informing via MsgBox that the connection failed. Why not analyze the ex variable through a debugger, or at least print out its string representation -- e.g., `MsgBox(ex.ToString())` By doing so you will get a much better idea as to why the query is failing.

Comment: Where's your connection string?!

Comment: my connection string  is :                                                                               ConStr.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Qwerty123;database=database;"                        I'd already connect it .

Comment: @nb1987,   Thank you  Atleast I got  the logic here :)  thanks thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have closed all previous connections.  Add the line

```
If(ConStr != ConnectionState.Open)
```

before opening the connection again

This will check for the connection being open before you try to open it again.

For the Catch, use

```
MsgBox("Connection Failed!" & Ex.Message)
```

to show the actual exception being thrown.

Also, unless you need to return records, using
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
is preferred method to run an action query.

Comment: Thank you  Atleast I got  the logic here :)  thanks thanks!!

Comment: what is the exception message you are getting? Would help further troubleshooting.

Comment: Another thing to look into is using parameter queries instead of adding the fields into the SQL string. This will help with escaping characters and is best practice for avoiding injection attacks